# May Codeception do Acceptance Testing to Element Style

Tags: codeception

I want to to do Acceptance Testing By Codeception . I want to  assert a element Style .

```
<div id="test" style="width:120px; height:100px">Test</div>
```

I want to check this div, it's width is 120px. May Codeception can Testing that case .

How can I do ?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 solutions:

1) create an css based on style attribute and check if present, will not work if style is not defined in line

```
#test[style*='120']
```

2) use `grabAttributeFrom` to the the attribute you need and check if contains desired value

```
$I->grabAttributeFrom('#test', 'style');
```

More details in [codeception documentation](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#grabAttributeFrom)